# Spring boot, remote host

Tags: java, spring-boot, remote-access

I want to check my rest api service remotely, for this purpose i add the following lines to application.properties

```
server.port = 8080
server.address  = 37.221.202.142
```

This ip address i got from this site https://2ip.ru/
But when i run my app i have the error like port is already in use. I switched a lot of ports( 8081,8082,8083 etc) but every time i got this error. When i removed this line from application.properties `server.address  = 37.221.202.142` Application is deployed fine but i can't connect to server using this url `http://37.221.202.142:8080/managers`, but this work fine http://localhost:8080/managers

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The correct way to do this is to have an actual (test) server to deploy onto - everything else will not give you proper results (even if you managed to make this IP-hackery work)

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and type **ipconfig**(if you are a windows user) or ifconfig(if your linux user).

Get the ip address of your machine. I assume you are not deploying the application in public server(**azure or aws**).

If your using **Tomcat or Pivotal Server** for deploying the war file. Double click on the sever to get the Overview of the server details and just type your IP address.

Now, restart the server and hit the IP address **YOURIPADDRESS:8080** port in the browser and it should work.

[image]